# SQL Server- How to count number of values in multiple columns and insert into another table with row values as columns and columns as row values

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a table in SQL server with values like below-

| Item | A | B | C | D | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | Yes | No | Yes | NA | 20210801 |
| P2 | Yes | Yes | Yes | NA | 20210801 |
| P3 | Yes | Yes | No | No | 20210801 |
| P4 | Yes | No | NA | No | 20210801 |
| P5 | No | NA | No | Yes | 20210801 |
| P6 | NA | NA | Yes | No | 20210801 |
| P1 | Yes | No | Yes | NA | 20210901 |
| P2 | Yes | Yes | Yes | NA | 20210901 |
| P3 | No | No | Yes | NA | 20210901 |
| P4 | Yes | No | NA | No | 20210901 |
| P5 | No | NA | No | Yes | 20210901 |
| P6 | NA | NA | Yes | No | 20210901 |

I want the count of each of the row values(Yes, No, NA) for every column, like below. The column names will be row values.

| Source | Yes | No | NA | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 2 | 1 | 20210901 |
| B | 1 | 3 | 2 | 20210901 |
| C | 4 | 1 | 1 | 20210901 |
| D | 1 | 2 | 3 | 20210901 |

The code will run with a specific value in where clause for Date column (e.g. WHERE Date ='20210901')

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: The question i have is what will you run the code with and what will use the data in final product. Will it be direct queries to database? or maybe some C# application? Python? etc. The reason I'm asking is that with all languages there are others solutions (ex. Dapper) to achieve this. But if you want to get data from one table and get it in specific format then answer by Gordon is ok from what i see.

Comment: @KrzysiekMastalerz  In SQL Server DB - Using Store Procedure, I want to update the 2nd table, using data in 1st table.
Thank you for your response. As for answer by Gordon, I am trying to understand & try it, as I am not aware how unpivot works exactly.

Comment: [link](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php) - Here you can find some answers regarding cross function.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to unpivot using `apply` and aggregate:

```
select t.source, t.date, v.*
from t cross apply
     (select sum(case when x = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as num_yes,
             sum(case when x = 'No' then 1 else 0 end) as num_no,
             sum(case when x = 'NA' then 1 else 0 end) as num_na          
      from (values (a), (b), (c), (d)) v(x)
     ) v;
```